# Hosting CLR: Calling .NET constructors/methods reflectively from C++, when some parameters are Enums

Tags: c++, .net, reflection, com, clr

I have a native program that hosts the CLR (i.e. starts it up manually, gets a reference to an `AppDomain`, etc. - this is **not** C++/CLI). Within that context, I want to instantiate a `FileStream` object.

To my understanding, the best way of creating objects in this context is to use reflection:

```
SAFEARRAY* pArgs = SafeArrayCreateVector(VT_VARIANT, 0, 2);
...
BSTR assemblyName = SysAllocString(L"mscorlib");
BSTR typeName = SysAllocString(L"System.IO.FileStream");
pAppDomain->CreateInstance_3(assemblyName, typeName, VARIANT_TRUE, BindingFlags_Default, NULL, pArgs, NULL, NULL, NULL, &result);
```

This works fine for all sorts of other types I've tried to create; e.g. `MemoryStream`. But `FileStream` specifically has got me stumped, seemingly because `FileStream` expects `Enum` types in its constructor (e.g. `System.IO.FileAccess`). If I try to give it a `VT_I4` (the base type of the Enum) in the place of the `FileAccess` parameter, it complains that it can't find the constructor (`HRESULT` is `COR_E_MISSINGMETHOD`) - which does make sense... but given Enums are value types, there's no obvious VARIANT type to use.

Is there a way to use reflection in the context of using a hosted CLR, to invoke arbitrary constructors/methods, when some of the parameters are Enums?

Comment: `VT_RECORD` maybe?

Comment: That's not possible.  Possible workarounds are to call Type.GetConstructor() so you can call the FileStream constructor you want directly and, easier, just to write a little helper assembly in C# that takes care of the tough cases.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, constants need to be "boxed"; passing them as integers fails. I found a way to do that when writing a low-level library to access .NET. What worked for me was to generate the constants at run-time:

- generate a compiler object
- compile and run the code below to generate an assembly containing a BoxHelper object with a Box method,
- create a BoxHelper object and invoke on it Box(name of the assembly, name of the constant type, value of the constant)
  in your case, something like: myBoxHelper.Box("mscorlib", "System.IO.FileAccess", 1)
  with the following values:

  FileAccess_Read = 1,
  FileAccess_Write = 2,
  FileAccess_ReadWrite = 3

The source code to send to the compiler:
"using System; using System.Reflection; using System.Runtime.InteropServices; public class BoxHelper {public IntPtr Box(string assem, string typ, int valu) {Type t=Type.GetType(typ); if(t==null){Assembly a=Assembly.LoadWithPartialName(assem); t = a.GetType(typ);}; return Marshal.GetIUnknownForObject(Enum.ToObject(t,valu));}}"

hope it helps